# Specify RPATH for externally built CMAKE project

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

How do I specify an RPATH for a project that was built externally in CMake (using 3.0.0) via `ExternalProject_Add()` macro?

For reference, let's say my ExternalProject is SFML. My external project call looks like:

```
  set(SFML_INSTALL_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ext-deps/ext-sfml-build")
  set(SFML_RPATH "${SFML_INSTALL_PATH}/src/lib")
  set(SFML_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DUSE_STATIC_LIBS:BOOL=true
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${SFML_INSTALL_PATH}
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH:PATH=${SFML_RPATH})

  ExternalProject_Add(ext-sfml
    GIT_REPOSITORY "${SFML_REPO}"
    GIT_TAG        "${SFML_TAG}"
    URL             SFML_URL
    URL_HASH        256=${SFML_SHA256}
    CMAKE_ARGS     "${SFML_CMAKE_ARGS}"
    TMP_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXT_DEPS_PREFIX}/ext-sfml-tmp"
    STAMP_DIR      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXT_DEPS_PREFIX}/ext-sfml-stamp"
    INSTALL_DIR    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXT_DEPS_PREFIX}/ext-sfml-build"
    SOURCE_DIR     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXT_DEPS_PREFIX}/ext-sfml"
    BINARY_DIR     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXT_DEPS_PREFIX}/ext-sfml-build"
    TEST_COMMAND "")
```

The error command I get when I run the build step (configuration is fine) is

```
Make Error at src/cmake_install.cmake:45 (file):
  file RPATH_CHANGE could not write new RPATH:

    /home/hendrix/repo/project/build/ext_deps/ext_sfml-build/lib

  to the file:

    /home/hendrix/repo/project/build/ext_deps/ext_sfml-build/bin/exe
```

Finally, this "/home/hendrix/repo/project/build/ext_deps/ext_sfml-build/lib" is the line I'm trying to modify. It appears that it is the value of my ${CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH} variable but containing the install prefix of my ext-dep project and not the top-level master project.

Comment: I just noticed there might be a problem with my `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` because it points to the directory of my top-level CMake project. How do I point it to the ExternalProject install dir?

Comment: You declare variable `SFML_CMALE_ARGS` as a list contained several elements. But when dereference this variable, you enclose it into *double quotes*, so it is treated as **single-value** variable. Drop double quotes, and parameters will be passed correctly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Tried removing the quotes but I got the same error message. The RPATH doesn't appear to be the same as the one in ${SFML_CMAKE_ARGS}

Comment: Probably, SFML project sets RPATH by itself, or adjust some other variables which affect on RPATH handling. For testing, you may create git repo with your own project. In that project you may add `message()` calls for variables, which are passed to it via `CMAKE_ARGS` option of `ExternalProject_Add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out (thanks to Tsyvarev's comments). The externally built project that I was using set it's own RPATH. So the string that I found in the error message was that RPATH, not any RPATH which I set in my "top-level" project.

It appears that setting the RPATH of an external project can not override that external project's internally set RPATH (if it is using CMAKE).